# calculating and graphing rates per category in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on an employee attrition problem. I have columns for department and if the employee quit or not.

Since some departments have more employees working in them, I would assume that they account for the majority of attrition.

So I would like to graph the attrition rate per department. For example, out of the 1000 people that work in IT 200 quit (20% attrition rate).

What I have been doing is creating pivot tables and cross table to get the relevant information then calculating manually attrition rates. But I feel like this can be done more efficiently.

What I have currently is:

1. Sample DataFrame

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'department': ['sales','sales','HR','sales','sales','HR','sales','R&D','HR','sales'],
                   'quit': ['yes','no','no','yes','no','yes','yes','no','yes','no'],
                   'employee_count': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

2. Pivot Table to find out how many employees are in each department

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='employee_count', 
                    columns=['department'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

which gives output of

| . | HR | R&D | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| employee_count | 3 | 1 | 6 |

3. Crosstab to find the number of employees that quit per department

```
pivot2=pd.crosstab(values=df['employee_count'],
                  index=df['department'],
                  columns=df['quit'],
                  aggfunc=np.sum)
```

| Quit | no | yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HR | 1 | 2 |
| R&D | 1 | nan |
| Sales | 3 | 3 |

4. Calculate Manually and Plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'white'
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

names = ['HR','sales']
values = [66.66666667,50]

plt.figure()
plt.bar(names, values)
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas offers to group by certain columns. In your case we can aggregate the results based on the department and whether someone quit. Then use a pivot to change the format of the table and finally calculate the total number of employees and quit rate:

```
# obtain the relevant results by grouping
agg_df = df.groupby(by=['department', 'quit']).agg({'employee_count': 'sum'})
agg_df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)

# pivot the table for further usage
pivot_df = agg_df.pivot(columns=['quit'], index=['department'], values='employee_count')
pivot_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# calculate final statistics
pivot_df['total'] = pivot_df['yes'] + pivot_df['no']
pivot_df['quit_rate'] = pivot_df['yes'] / pivot_df['total']
```